# Phonegap cordova 2.3.0 phonegap-facebook-plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to setup the facebook connect plugin on my ios phonegap applications, I followed the steps in the link below

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

and completed it 100% but when I run the app It showing this error in the console

```
2013-04-24 13:43:10.009 ShoBingg[2538:19a03] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2013-04-24 13:43:10.010 ShoBingg[2538:19a03] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-04-24 13:43:10.010 ShoBingg[2538:19a03] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect467591405","org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","init",["427370550688587"]]
2013-04-24 13:43:10.010 ShoBingg[2538:19a03] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2013-04-24 13:43:10.010 ShoBingg[2538:19a03] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-04-24 13:43:10.010 ShoBingg[2538:19a03] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect467591406","org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","getLoginStatus",[]]
```

I searched on the internet about this error and everyone had the same error fixed it with add the line of code below in the config.xml

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
```

and I added it but I am still have the same error?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue. did u fixed it???

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this to your config.xml ?

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    </feature>
```

I had the same issue, added this and it worked for me : 
[source](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/issues/20)

Please note this was only tested on phonegap cordova 3.0

Comment: can you please accept the answer if solution worked. Thanks. This appears to be a missing piece in the documentation on the facebook phonegap plugin.